# Walking file tree in Java 6

Tags: java, file, filesystems

I'm trying to find a way to locate a certain file in the computer's directory in java 6. More specifically, my program launches the program Pymol by locating pymol.exe on the hard drive and executing a command to launch it. I have it working fine in Java 7, by using the File Visitor interface. However, I'm trying to make it compatible with Java 6, so I need to find an alternate method for locating this program (or identifying that the user does not have it installed). Any ideas?

Comment: I thin you should find it in PATH

Comment: Use a recursive function calling [File.listFiles(FilenameFilter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FilenameFilter)) or better FileFilter for fetching subdirectories too.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
File findFile(String name, File dir) {
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile() && f.getName().equals(name)) {
            return f;
        }
    }
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            return findFile(name, f);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: When i run this method it returns null, though I know the file I'm looking for is there

Comment: It seems like it's going through the first folder it encounters, checking for the name, then returning null rather than going through other folders in the root directory

Comment: This is the idea I am running from. getting all files. Then doing a second run on them. It is more efficient to get file, do stuff, get file, ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a recursive tree traversal in your file directory until you either find the file or the traversal ends.